# how to create a jar file with maven and use it in a different computer?

Tags: java, maven, jar, executable-jar

I created an automation java project using maven and I want to use this project on a different computer with a different environment.

Is there anyway I can create a jar file of my project and use it on a different computer?

Thanks

Comment: It might help you : https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-jar-file-with-maven/

Comment: What do you mean by "use"? To execute it? To use it in another Java project? To start it on a server?

Comment: I was able to generate a jar file by using mvn install. By use I mean, if another developer that works on a different repository in a different place can use the jar file that I generated if I will send it to him?

Answer (score 0):

You can use maven-jar-plugin. A simple configuration that you can use is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>Main class path</mainClass>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Build-Title>buildNumber</Build-Title>
                <Implementation-Build>artifactId</Implementation-Build>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
        <forceCreation>true</forceCreation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: what this configuration actually does?

Comment: I generated a jar file already. I just don't know if I can share it with other developers